# Calculation of a partial derivative arising in a physics class.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

> This is an electronics question, but I chose to ask it here because ***my
>   doubt is primarily related to mathematics***.

I have been given the following equations:

$$V_T=I_BR_T+V_{BE}+(I_B+I_C) R_E \tag1$$
$$=> I_B=\frac{V_T-V_{BE}-I_CR_E}{R_T+R_E} \tag2$$
$$I_C=\beta I_B+(1+\beta)I_{CO} \tag3$$
Substituting $ I_B $ from 2nd eq to 3rd eq yields:
$$I_C=\beta\frac{V_T-V_{BE}-I_CR_E}{R_T+R_E}+(1+ \beta)I_{CO} \tag4$$

### $$ I_C(1+\frac{\beta R_E}{R_T+R_E})=\frac{\beta(V_T-V_{BE})}{R_T+R_E}+(1+\beta)I_{CO} \tag {4a}$$

$$S=\frac{\partial I_C}{\partial I_{CO}}=\frac{1+\beta}{1+\frac{\beta R_E}{R_T+R_E}} \tag5$$

$$S'=\frac{\partial I_C}{\partial V_{BE}}=-\frac{\beta}{(1+\beta)R_E+R_T} \tag6$$

> I have to prove $$S''=\frac{\partial I_C}{\partial \beta}=\frac{1}{\beta(1+\beta)}[I_C\frac{(R_T+R_E)(1+\beta)-\beta SR_E}{R_T+R_E}+SI_{CO} \tag7
> ]$$
>
> However, 
>   I am getting $$ \frac{\partial I_C}{\partial \beta}=\frac{1}{\beta(1+\beta)}[I_C\frac{(R_T+R_E)(1+\beta)-\beta SR_E}{R_T+R_E}-SI_{CO} $$ instead of   $$\frac{\partial I_C}{\partial\beta}=\frac{1}{\beta(1+\beta)}[I_C\frac{(R_T+R_E)(1+\beta)+\beta SR_E}{R_T+R_E}+SI_{CO} $$
>
> DERIVATION(MY ATTEMPT):

Partial differentiating eq 4a with respect to $ \beta $:

$$\frac{\partial I_C}{\partial\beta}(1+\frac{\beta R_E}{R_T+R_E})+I_C\frac{R_E}{R_T+R_E}=\frac{V_T-V_{BE}}{R_T+R_E}+I_{CO} \tag 8$$
$$\frac{\partial I_C}{\partial \beta}(1+\frac{\beta R_E}{R_T+R_E})=\frac{V_T-V_{BE}-I_CR_E}{R_T+R_E}+I_{CO} \tag 9$$

$$\frac{\partial I_C}{\partial \beta}=\frac{V_T-V_{BE}-I_CR_E}{(R_T+R_E)(1+\frac{\beta R_E}{R_T+R_E})}+\frac{I_{CO}}{(1+\frac{\beta R_E}{R_T+R_E})}\frac{1+\beta}{1+\beta} \tag {9a}$$

From eq 4a:

$$ I_C=\frac{\beta(V_T-V_{BE}}{(R_T+R_E)(1+\frac{\beta R_E}{R_T+R_E})}\frac{1+\beta}{1+\beta}+\frac{(1+\beta)I_{CO}}{(1+\frac{\beta R_E}{R_T+R_E})} \tag {10}$$

$$I_C=\frac{\beta(V_T-V_{BE})S}{(1+\beta)(R_T+R_E}+SI_{CO} \tag{11}$$
$$=> (V_T-V_{BE})=\frac{(1+\beta)(R_T+R_E)}{\beta S}(I_C-SI_{CO}) \tag{12}$$

Substituting eq 12 in eq 10

$$\frac{\partial I_C}{\partial \beta}=\frac{\frac{(1+\beta)(R_T+R_E)}{\beta S}(I_C-SI_{CO})-I_CR_E}{(R_T+R_E)(1+\frac{\beta R_E}{R_T+R_E})}+\frac{S}{1+\beta} I_{CO} \tag{13}$$

$$ \frac{\partial I_C}{\partial \beta}=\frac{\frac{(1+\beta)(R_T+R_E)}{\beta S}I_C-I_CR_E}{(R_T+R_E)(1+\frac{\beta R_E}{R_T+R_E})}+\frac{S}{1+\beta}I_{CO}-\frac{\frac{(1+\beta)(R_T+R_E)}{\beta S}SI_{CO}}{(R_T+R_E)(1+\frac{\beta R_E}{R_T+R_E})} \tag{14}$$

$$=\frac{1+\beta}{1+\beta}\frac{(1+\beta)(R_T+R_E)I_C-\beta SR_EI_C}{\beta S(R_T+R_E)(1+\frac{\beta R_E}{R_T+R_E})}+\frac{S}{1+\beta}I_{CO}-\frac{S}{\beta}I_{CO} \tag{15}$$

$$=\frac{SI_C[(1+\beta)(R_T+R_E)-\beta SR_E}{\beta(1+\beta)S(R_T+R_E)}+SI_{CO}[\frac{\beta-1-\beta}{\beta(1+\beta)}] \tag{16}$$

$$\frac{\partial I_C}{\partial \beta}=\frac{I_C[(1+\beta)(R_T+R_E)-\beta SR_E}{\beta(1+\beta)(R_T+R_E)}-\frac{SI_{CO}}{\beta(1+\beta)} \tag{17}$$

$$\frac{\partial I_C}{\partial \beta}=\frac{1}{\beta(1+\beta)}[I_C\frac{(R_T+R_E)(1+\beta)-\beta SR_E}{R_T+R_E}-SI_{CO} ]\tag{18}$$

> The sign of the last term should be +ve. Where might have I gone wrong?

Comment: You can use \nabla for $\nabla$

Comment: @Dave Sir, corrected.

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing with $S$. What variable are you differentiating with respect to to go from (5) to (6)?

Comment: @copper.hat I have been given eq 1 till 6. From those I need to arrive at 7, where i am basically finding partial derivative of $I_C$ w.r.t beta.

Comment: @copper.hat S is a known term given by eq 5 .Similarly S' is another known term. Here S ,S'ans S''  are just different variables....S' is not a derivative of S nor is S'' a derivative of S'. S denotes $\frac{\partial I_C}{\partial I_{CO}} $ , S' denotes $\frac{\partial I_C}{\partial V_{BE}}$, S'' denotes $\frac{\partial I_C}{\partial \beta}$